# DB technology for efficient search in tabular data?

Tags: database, search, full-text-search

We have a repository of tables. Around 200 tables, each table can be thousands of rows, all tables are originally in Excel sheets.

Each table has a different scheme. All data is text or numbers.

We would like to create an application that allows free text search on all tables (we define which columns will be searched in each table) efficiently - speed is important.
**The main dilemma is which DB technology we should choose.**

We created a mock up by importing all tables to MS SQL Server, and creating a full text index over them.  The search is done using the CONTAINS keyword. This solution works well for a small number of tables, but it doesn't scale.

We thought about a NoSQL solution, but we don't yet have any experience in it.

Our limitations (which unfortunately I can not effect): Windows servers only. But we can install on them whatever we want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ElasticSearch! It's a search server based on Apache Lucene and has a clean REST- and JavaScript-based API. Although it's used usually as a search-index for a primary database, it can also be used stand-alone. So you may want to write a backup routine for a few of your tables/data and try it out.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElasticSearch

Comparison of ElasticSearch and Apache Solr (another Lucene-based search server): 
https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dc6zhtt5_1frfxwfff&pli=1

Comment: Is it recommended for use on windows servers?

Comment: Never tried, but since it is primarly based on Java, I think it should work quite well.

http://captaincodeman.com/2011/05/20/elasticsearch-windows-service-2008-x64/

Comment: Why 200 tables?  That seems like too many.  Using PostgreSQL I would create one table with one document per row  with the spreadsheet  stored as a text type. That type can be indexed and  searched http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX